# In Java SNMP4J, how to find the versions of snmp4j.jar and SNMP4J-agent.jar?

Tags: java, snmp4j

How can I find out the jar version from the snmp4j.jar and SNMP4J-agent.jar files.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the version of the JAR files you are using if the `META-INF\maven\org.snmp4j\snmp4j\pom.properties` file exists.

If it does you can read this file from the JAR and load the version property.

Answer (score 0):

You can unzip the .jar. A .jar is just a another format of a .zip archive with additional info.

Open it up in 7-zip or some other ZIP utility. This should allow you to inspect the contents of the jar. If the pom.properties doesn't exist in there, then poke around. You may be able to  find some other file which contains the version info. There should be a VersionInfo class in the following directory org\snmp4j\version. That would be a good place to start, if you wanted to figure out, using your favourite java decompiler.